# How to use Intel AVX on QNX Neutrino 6.5.0?

Tags: avx, qnx, qnx-neutrino

I recently started working with QNX 6.5.0 and can't understand how in QNX develop programs using Intel AVX. Installed QNX Development Studio 6.5.0 with GCC 4.4.2, I'm trying to write a simple program, but the build fails.

```
#include <immitnrin.h>
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
   __m256 var;
   __m256 var2;
   __m256 result;

   var = _mm256_set1_ps(1.f);
   var2 = _mm256_set1_ps(3.f);
   result = _mm256_add_ps(var,var2);

   return 0;
}
```

> error: immitnrin.h: No such file or directory
>   In function 'int main(int, char**)':
>   error: '__m256' was not declared in this scope
>   error: expected ';' before 'var'
>   error: expected ';' before 'var2'
>   error: expected ';' before 'result'
>   error: 'var' was not declared in this scope
>   error: '_mm256_set1_ps' was not declared in this scope
>   error: 'var2' was not declared in this scope
>   error: 'result' was not declared in this scope
>   error: '_mm256_add_ps' was not declared in this scope

How and where can I learn how to work with SIMD instructions Intel in QNX?

### Update

Here's the output from the program make.exe:

> make.exe -k CPULIST=x86 all --file=C:/DOCUME~1/Andrew/LOCALS~1/Temp/QMakefile.tmp 
>   C:/QNX650/host/win32/x86/usr/bin/make.exe -j 1 -Cx86 -fMakefile all
>   make.exe[1]: Entering directory `C:/ide-4.7-workspace/project_test_avx/x86'
>
>   C:/QNX650/host/win32/x86/usr/bin/make.exe -j 1 -Co -fMakefile all
>
>   make.exe[2]: Entering directory`C:/ide-4.7-workspace/project_test_avx/x86/o'

Comment: Please also include the command you used to compile. If you used make, include the output of `make -n <target>`

Comment: Added output of the make program, which comes as part of the environment QNX Momentics IDE.